# how can I move the next button on the right in the gallery pop to be near the image when each image is a different size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been asked to create an image gallery for a test website for a mini project as I am learning about html and css. I have created the gallery and the pop up images based on the code here: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

When I click on the images, I can see the next and previous arrow buttons however the next button on the right hand side is to the far right when I am trying to move it slightly to the left so that it is inline with the image. Each image is required to be a different size[next button position][1] In this image, I have circled where the next button currently is and then circled in red where I am trying to move it.

Is it possible to amend this code so the the next button is auto aligned regardless of the image size?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* Style the Image Used to Trigger the Modal */
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  columns: 4;
}

.myImg {
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 1px;
    }

.myImg:hover {opacity: 0.7;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content (Image) */
.modal-content {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 700px;

}

/* Add Animation - Zoom in the Modal */
.modal-content, #caption {
    -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
    animation-name: zoom;
    animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from {transform:scale(0)}
    to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: auto;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}
/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Image Modal</h2>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Trigger the Modal -->
<div class="image-container">
<img class="myImg" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1U4Z-2GJcRDtIAmZt4ej0MOF_NvA0ntzS" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">

<img class="myImg" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1cfqbl28ezKPikIXApzZQOEUPwKm2AKrr" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">

<img class="myImg" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1I-bDFOoYZ-XUZkwDxRJmtiR_7DGVn_Eb" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">

<img class="myImg" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1DU-S82guX9KooYyfDavkg1M_kpXAVrs1" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">

<img class="myImg" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=10PElUch6-oxpjga6Pe6PoHd2VUXZkUfu" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(5)" class="hover-shadow cursor">

<img class="myImg" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1U4Z-2GJcRDtIAmZt4ej0MOF_NvA0ntzS" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(6)" class="hover-shadow cursor">

<img class="myImg" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1HAh9siwne5Fa39G2qIppry-aHrrFRrzb" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(7)" class="hover-shadow cursor">

<img class="myImg" src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1TwVoVT9UxlmmQO125b-lD7kbswYqCdgy" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(8)" class="hover-shadow cursor">


</div> <!-- end image-container div -->
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">


    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 8</div>
      <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1U4Z-2GJcRDtIAmZt4ej0MOF_NvA0ntzS" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 8</div>
      <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1cfqbl28ezKPikIXApzZQOEUPwKm2AKrr" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 8</div>
      <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1I-bDFOoYZ-XUZkwDxRJmtiR_7DGVn_Eb" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 8</div>
      <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1DU-S82guX9KooYyfDavkg1M_kpXAVrs1" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">5 / 8</div>
      <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=10PElUch6-oxpjga6Pe6PoHd2VUXZkUfu" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">6 / 8</div>
      <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1U4Z-2GJcRDtIAmZt4ej0MOF_NvA0ntzS" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">7 / 8</div>
      <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1HAh9siwne5Fa39G2qIppry-aHrrFRrzb" style="width:100%">
    </div>

        <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">8 / 8</div>
      <img src="https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1TwVoVT9UxlmmQO125b-lD7kbswYqCdgy" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  <!-- The Close Button -->
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>


</div>

<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: add `position:relative;` to `.modal-content`. Also w3Schools isn't the best place to get code from, or to learn Javascript (ECMAScript) from.

Comment: You've also removed the 'caption' element resulting in a script errors that you probably want to clean up

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, just add `position: relative` on `.modal-content`.

This way, absolute position of your arrows will be relative to the modal container and not the full screen.

Hope it'll help.

Comment: Just to be clearer with this. `absolute` positioned elements are relative to all parent containers that have a position style applied to them. This isn't always the viewport and could be a parent further up the DOM tree.

Comment: glad it helped @uzi :)